# Extract bits with SIMD

Tags: x86, bit-manipulation, simd, intrinsics, avx2

I want to extract 8 bits from a register variable `__mm256i src` with 8 position specified by another `__mm256i offset` which is composed of 8 integers.
For example: if `offset` is `[1,3,5,21,100,200,201,202]`, I want to get 1st,3rd,5th,100th,200th,201st,202nd bits from `src` and pack them to a `int8`.

This question is similar to [Extracting bits using bit manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444394/extracting-bits-using-bit-manipulation/46823977#46823977), but I want a solution with SIMD instructions, since it is much faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Select high 3 bits in each element and select required 32-bit element with using of intrinsic [_mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=3161,777,2028,4029,4037,4050,4240,85,4243,4251,4287,4649,6,16,33,4871,374,1225,4065,5562,403,403,1696,2985,595,2994,2313,2304,2313,3105,2982,2982,2991,2985,2843,1475,69,68,3844,5452,5483,4501,540,4064,376,3231,5509,5440,418,413,5509,241,242,307,4753,3240,5376,3032,3290,3142,3124,5534,3640,3628,3963,3999,3963,3963,3999,3987,3975,3771,1169,1169,1199,2211,2235,5439,1207,1206,4312,3285,231,1439,4741,4774,4768,4756,1436,3868,3941,3919,2629,2501,2569,2629,2501,159,211,4268,2418,4119,5238,3159,2841,2250,2251,2234,2303,2984,2840,3028,59,259,260,18,21,4559,4560,2114,4936,410,4927,1365,1365,7,0,4084,4087,432,2086,3251,3646,4791,2114,2115,3610,3610,4933,3942,3941,3615,3615,3941&text=_mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32)().
2. Select low 5 bits in each elements of vector and create bit mask with using of intrinsic [_mm256_sllv_epi32](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=3161,777,2028,4029,4037,4050,4240,85,4243,4251,4287,4649,6,16,33,4871,374,1225,4065,5562,403,403,1696,2985,595,2994,2313,2304,2313,3105,2982,2982,2991,2985,2843,1475,69,68,3844,5452,5483,4501,540,4064,376,3231,5509,5440,418,413,5509,241,242,307,4753,3240,5376,3032,3290,3142,3124,5534,3640,3628,3963,3999,3963,3963,3999,3987,3975,3771,1169,1169,1199,2211,2235,5439,1207,1206,4312,3285,231,1439,4741,4774,4768,4756,1436,3868,3941,3919,2629,2501,2569,2629,2501,159,211,4268,2418,4119,5238,3159,2841,2250,2251,2234,2303,2984,2840,3028,59,259,260,18,21,4559,4560,2114,4936,410,4927,1365,1365,7,0,4084,4087,432,2086,3251,3646,4791,2114,2115,3610,3610,4933,3942,3941,3615,3615,3941,4933&text=_mm256_sllv_epi32)().
3. Pack result to int8 with using of [_mm256_movemask_ps](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=3161,777,2028,4029,4037,4050,4240,85,4243,4251,4287,4649,6,16,33,4871,374,1225,4065,5562,403,403,1696,2985,595,2994,2313,2304,2313,3105,2982,2982,2991,2985,2843,1475,69,68,3844,5452,5483,4501,540,4064,376,3231,5509,5440,418,413,5509,241,242,307,4753,3240,5376,3032,3290,3142,3124,5534,3640,3628,3963,3999,3963,3963,3999,3987,3975,3771,1169,1169,1199,2211,2235,5439,1207,1206,4312,3285,231,1439,4741,4774,4768,4756,1436,3868,3941,3919,2629,2501,2569,2629,2501,159,211,4268,2418,4119,5238,3159,2841,2250,2251,2234,2303,2984,2840,3028,59,259,260,18,21,4559,4560,2114,4936,410,4927,1365,1365,7,0,4084,4087,432,2086,3251,3646,4791,2114,2115,3610,3610,4933,3942,3941,3615,3615,3941,4933&text=_mm256_movemask_ps)() (cast __m256i to __m256).

There is an example below:

```
uint8_t Select(__m256i offset, __m256i src)
{
    __m256i permutedSrc = _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32(src, _mm256_srli_epi32(offset, 5));
    __m256i shift = _mm256_and_si256(offset, _mm256_set1_epi32(31));
    __m256i bitmask = _mm256_sllv_epi32(_mm256_set1_epi32(1), shift);
    __m256i mask = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(_mm256_and_si256(permutedSrc, bitmask), _mm256_setzero_si256());
    return ~_mm256_movemask_ps(_mm256_castsi256_ps(mask));
}
```

Comment: I wonder if `VPSHUFBITQMB` will help here. Though we won't be seeing that instruction until Ice Lake.